# How to make my fixed header appear in front of the body?

Tags: php, html, css

I design fixed header and main box, but the problem is when I scroll the page the box come over the header since the header is fixed. why it is coming like that? How to solve this `position: fixed` stacking order issue?

[image]

```css
header{
background-color: black;   
width:100%;
height: 50px; 
position: fixed;
}

.mainbox{
width: 800px;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;  
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 5px;
top: 55px;
left: 50%; 
margin-left: -500px; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should increase the `z-index` property in your header

```
header {
  background-color: black;   
  width:100%;
  height: 50px; 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

### **What is the use of `z-index`?**

It specifies the stack order of an element. Element which have higher stack order is always in front of the element with lower stack. For example, if your header has `z-index: 10` and your mainbox has `z-index: 9`, then your header is stacked in front of your mainbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should add z index property for header in css i.e. z-index:2

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` property can do what you want from css.
I have just commented margin-left from css, to showcase you result. You can keep it as it is in your code.

Run below code. I hope it will solve your CSS issue.

```css
header{
background-color: black;   
width:100%;
height: 50px; 
position: fixed;
z-index:20;
color: white;
}

.mainbox{
width: 800px;
height: 100%;
background-color: green;  
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 5px;
top: 55px;
left: 50%; 
/**margin-left: -500px;*/
z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header class="header">
  This header
</header>
<div class="mainbox">
  Here will be list of questions by php
</div>

</html>
```